# Blender 2.8 faces not visible

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface, vertex-groups

I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM

on modeling. At 18:52 before adding a subdivision surface modifier my object looks like:

[image]

After subsurf:

[image]

It looks like two overlapping planes but I don't see the vertices that create them (I've already cleaned 
up double vertices).

How can I remove that face so that I don't get that wedge after subsurf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out; simply delete the faces in question, recreate edge between vertexes, create face from new edge. I'm not sure this is the best way of going about it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a normal issue. Select the entire mesh with <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.